# Power MOSFET behaving differently at high Vds

Tags: powermosfet

I am trying to switch a circuit continuously by pulsing a power MOSFET(IXTN660N04T4) with a function generator. I have attached my set-up below. IXTH500N04T2 was only used for simulation. Their specs are very similar.

***Edit:

- the current limiter in the circuit below is to replicate the actual power supply that I am using. It is a variable supply  max 40V or 20A at 800W.
- the simulation showed similar results with and without the 1ohm test resistor I mentioned. Currently, it is used so that I can hook up the oscilloscope without causing a short. It won't be included when conducting the experiment.

Here are the current parameters for the setup:

- Pulse period: 200us
- Pulse width: 20 us
- Pulse pk-pk: (0V-10V)
- Load: 130mOhm to 500 mOhm depending on the temperature (current)

For testing the circuit, an 1ohm power resistor is attached between the source and the ground to measure the waveform using an oscilloscope.

When the power supply voltage (V1) is below 25V, the circuit behaves as expected:

- resistance values throughout the circuit checked out
- voltage drops through the components checked out
- The waveform from the function generator and the waveform across the 1ohm resistor matched.
- The current through the load was proportional to the pulse width

However, when V1 is higher than 30V(to 35V) and all other parameter remains the same, the "polarity of the pulse" seems to switch.

- From the oscilloscope measurement, the switch is on when the input pulse is off.
- The current decreases when the pulse width increases.

I have verified that all the parameters are within the specs sheet.

Please help!
[image]

Comment: What does the voltage on the current limiter look like along with the  voltage to the load?

Comment: I don't see the 1 ohm resistor in the circuit?

Comment: VoltageSpike  and Andy aka, I have updated my post for clarification. Thanks!